# PHP 5.6 SoapClient passing decimal bug

Tags: php, soap, decimal

I'm trying to parse an PHP array to SOAP XML with the SoapClient function.
I have to parse a decimal number to SOAP. My PHP array looks lik this:

```
$contactparams = array(

"DECIMALVARIABLE"=>0.00

);
```

When executing the SOAP call I'm getting the error thrown that I should use a decimal number with 2 decimals. My guess it that the PHP function converts the 0.00 to plain 0.

Example of the error thrown:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Client] Invalid
>   number 2dp value (0)

When I use 0.01 it works just fine.

I've already tried to parse it as a string "0.00" & 0.00.""

I've also tried the number_format function to create the 0.00 but with the same result.

Any ideas how to solve this riddle would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the type for the field in the soap contract (wsdl)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly but: <s:element name="DECIMALVARIABLE" type="omnis:shortnumber2dp"/> Maybe the integration link is of more value: http://samacom.dyndns.org:5912/davewslink/integration.wsdl

Comment: When you do "0.00" what does the error look like?
How about trying to throw in a space at either end?

Comment: I think `var_dump(0.00)` shows that there is nothing to be done about this. PHP seems to treat zero as an integer. Maybe a packet capture with Wireshark would confirm what goes out over the wire. Are you in WSDL mode?

Comment: Is there a way to convert the php array into another type of array before passing it through the SOAP function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of searching for a solution I've finally found a devious one...

When entering the value 0.001 SOAP's functions changes this to the correct value of 0.00

SO:

```
$contactparams = array(

"DECIMALVARIABLE"=>0.001

);
```

GIVES:

```
DECIMALVALUE=0.00
```

Not quite a clean solution, but one that works..

Answer (score 1):

this dirty trick can help you understand is this error really related to you decimal variable

```
<?php

class MySoapClient extends SoapClient
{
    public $decimalValue;
    function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version) {
        if (is_null($this->decimalValue) 
            throw new Exception("you forgot to set decimalValue");
        $request = str_replace('#decimalValuePlaceHolder#', $this->decimalValue, $request);
        $ret = parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version);
        $this->__last_request = $request;
        return $ret;
    } 
}

// usage
$contactparams = array(
    "DECIMALVARIABLE"=>'#decimalValuePlaceHolder#',
);

$client = new MySoapClient(); // initialize this as prev SoapClient
$client->decimalValue = "0.00"; // or number_format($someNumber, 2); // any decimal variable
$client->callFunction(); // call you function as you did before
```

Comment: I am already positive that this error relates to my decimal variable. Thanks anyway

Comment: and then you can use this to solve your case. adjust str_replace to your needs and you will be able to send desired values

Comment: Using `str_replace()` suggests it would just send it as a string, which is already stated does not work.

Answer (score 1):

**Fields of the type “shortnumber2dp” must be delivered with 2 decimals : 0.00 and not 0**

Make sure that you don't pass an empty string in number_format

```
echo "A. ".number_format(null, 2)."\n";
// output 0.00
echo "B. ".number_format(0, 2)."\n";
// output 0.00
echo "C. ".number_format('', 2)."\n";
// error
```

Fix this issue

```
if(empty($value)){$value = 0;}
```

Comment: Hi peter, when doing a print_r of my PHP array I'm getting the correct values: [DECIMALVARIABLE] => 0.00, however when converting the php array to SOAP I think they adjust the 0.00 value to plain 0

Comment: @JoeriMinnekeer are there equivalent types that you can pass this variable? e.g. `decimal` in type="omnis:shortnumber2dp"

Comment: If by any chance your situation has to do with this manual http://www.omnis.net/download/manuals/Omnis_Programming.pdf then if i was in your position i would try another type such as number 2dp and floating to see if there is no issue when using those types. If you still get problem then i would advise to post your soap class,function,code to make your question more complete.